# Circleci does not work with my config.yml file when trying to run 'pytest --html=pytest_report.html', producing the error 'no such option: --html'

Tags: python, flask, pytest, config, circleci

What I tried:
placing 'pip install --user -r requirements.txt' in the second run command
placing 'pip install pytest' in the second run command along with 'pip install pytest-html'

both followed by,
pytest --html=pytest_report.html

I am new to CircleCI and using pytest as well
Here is the steps portion of the config.yml file

```
version: 2.1
jobs:
  run_tests:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/python:3.9.1

    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
        name: Install Python Dependencies
        command:
          echo 'export PATH=~$PATH:~/.local/bin' >> $BASH_ENV && source $BASH_ENV
          pip install --user -r requirements.txt
      - run:
        name: Run Unit Tests
        command:
          pip install --user -r requirements.txt
          pytest --html=pytest_report.html
      - store_test_results:
          path: test-reports
      - store_artifacts:
          path: test-reports
workflows:
  build_test:
    jobs:
      - run_tests
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`--html` is not one of the builtin options for pytest -- it likely comes from a plugin

I believe you're looking for [pytest-html](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-html/) -- make sure that's listed in your requirements

it's also possible / likely that the `pip install --user` is installing another copy of `pytest` into the image which'll only be available at `~/.local/bin/pytest` instead of whatever `pytest` comes with the circle ci image

---

disclaimer, I'm one of the pytest core devs